# IOS animation finalizing

Tags: ios, animation

I have an app that animates the alpha of some images from 0 to 1 . If I go back to previous view with the `popToRootViewController` and then come back in this view , the animation continues from where it was when I pressed the back button . Also the " animation movie " starts again while the other animation is still in progress . Kind of two movies playing at once.

I display the images like this :

```
-(void)showStar2
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.3];
        [stars[1] setAlpha:1];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self showStar3];
    }];
```

Is there a way to stop the animation process when I press the back button ? I tried `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]` but still it doesn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to import the QuartzCore.h file.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and whenever you want to stop animation call this

```
[CATransaction begin];
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Doesn't work . If I go back and then back in this view , the animation is still showing .

Comment: Try removing animations from  stars[1].layer

Comment: instead of using block use older method of uiview animations in which you commit animation,That should work

Answer (score 0):

Put this before you create your starView(don't know how it's called)

```
if (starView!=nil){
        [starView removeFromSuperview];
        [starView release];
        starView = nil;
    }
starView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

This will remove your image before creating new one.

Or remove your image, when you close the view.